# $x^{p-1} + ... + x^2 + x + 1$ is irreducible using Eisenstein's criterion?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory, irreducible-polynomials

Eisenstein's criterion says that for a prime $p$ if the following conditions are satisfied for a primitive polynomial, $f(x)$, then that polynomial is irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$

$p \mid a_0, a_0, ..., a_{n-1}$

$p \not\mid a_n$

$p^2 \not\mid a_0^2$

Now I am almost certain I read somewhere that this lemma can be used to prove that the polynomial $x^{p-1} + x^{p-2} + ... + x^2 + x + 1$ is irreducible.

All coefficients are $1$ though and we have have an awkward amount of terms, $p - 1$ terms as opposed to $p$ terms - so how can Eisenstein's criterion be applied here?

Comment: Do you mean $x^{p-1}+x^{p-2}+....+1$?

Comment: Fixed the mistakes.

Comment: There is another issue. EC tells you $p^2$ does not divide $a_0$. The way you have it, that is, $p$ divides $a_0$ but $p^2$ does not divide $a_0^2$, Eisenstein' would be impossible to use =]

Answer (score 1):

You can't directly apply Eisenstein to $f$.
But you can combine it with the substitution criterion: Look at the substituted polynomial $g(x) = f(x+1)$.