# Prove the polynomial is irreducible

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, irreducible-polynomials

I tried this problem for a while, but didn't see the application of Eisenstein's irreducibility criterion here. All the coefficients, including the leading coefficient, are equal to 1.

p is a prime number.

The polynomial is $f(x) = x^{p-1} + x^{p-2} + \cdots + x + 1$

How do I proceed?
Many thanks.

Comment: Hint : try to show that $f(x+1)$ is irreducible and then deduce that $f(x)$ must be irreducible. Another way to do this is to realize that this is the cyclotomic polynomial $\Phi_p$ and hence irreducible (but you need to know that cyclotomic polynomials are always irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$).

Comment: ClémentGuérin's answer is a great way to proceed.  Might also be worth noting that this is the $p^{th}$ cyclotomic polynomial https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclotomic_polynomial.

Comment: Click on "Edit" to see how I used LaTeX to write the mathematical expressions. You can find a LaTeX guide on Meta.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/215042/irreducibility-of-xp-1-cdots-x1

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/87609/eisenstein-criterion-with-a-twist

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/588310/xp-1-x2-x-1-is-irreducible-using-eisensteins-criterion

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1277577/proof-that-fracxp-1x-1-1-x-dots-xp-1-is-irreducible

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/879119/if-p-is-a-prime-prove-that-xp-1-xp-2-xp-3-cdots-x1-is-irred

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$f(x) = \frac{x^p - 1}{x-1}$. [This division is valid in the fraction field of polynomials.]

Thus $f(t+1) = \frac{(t+1)^p - 1}{t}$.

Eisenstein's criterion applies and so $f(t+1)$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}[t]$.

Now $f(x)$ cannot be reducible in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ otherwise you could substitute $x$ by $(t+1)$ in a non-trivial factorization of $f(x)$ to get a non-trivial factorization of $f(t+1)$.

Comment: How does Eisenstein's Criterion apply?

Comment: @SR1: Expand and see.